# Evitar el ALT+F4

Tags: c#

estuve unos días intentando bloquear el Alt+F4 en C# pero aun usando este código no me funciona, me podrían ayudar?? Gracias

--CODIGO USADO--

```
private void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt || this.ModifierKeys == Keys.F4)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero estás usando un evento que solo se dispara cuando ya se está cerrando el formulario, por lo que no ve el alt+f4, pero tiene en el evento para cancelarlo, lo que tienes que hacer es hacer un booleano que se active en el evento keydown.

Código:

```
   bool prevaltf4;
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {



        prevaltf4 = e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F4) && e.Alt == true;
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (prevaltf4)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            prevaltf4=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya me he dado cuenta de mi error, es que estaba intentando usarlo en consola... Perdon por hacer perder tu tiempo